# How to remove innermap key using java 8 streams

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn Java Stream API, I have the following code

```
List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> map2 = new ArrayList<>();

HashMap<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("a1", "hermione");
innerMap.put("a2", "harry");
innerMap.put("a3", "ron");

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> outermap = new HashMap<>();
outermap.put("friends", innerMap);

List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(outermap);
```

I want to remove harry from inner map and the same structure ( `List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>`) should be retained, how do i achieve that using Streams API?

Comment: Streams don't modify the underlying object, instead it will give you a new object as per your operations.

Comment: as a side note, I'd recommend you use classes to model data rather than complicated, nested maps to represents a list of friends. following OOP is the ideal way to proceed and will make your life a lot better in terms of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) here as long as you only want to remove a certain map entry while keeping the whole structure:

```
list.forEach(map -> map.forEach(
    (key, value) -> value.entrySet()
        .removeIf(entry -> "harry".equals(entry.getValue()))));
```

If you insist on using Stream API, be prepare for complicated handling with entries and dictionaries themselves as long as the Stream API is suitable to work with collections. Take a look:

```
List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> newList = list.stream()
    .map(outer -> outer.entrySet().stream()
        .map(inner -> new SimpleEntry<>(
            inner.getKey(),
            inner.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> !"harry".equals(entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Moreover, as already stated, the classes are the way more suitable to represent such complicated data structures.